# MS Access SQL update first column of table query update all non selected column

Tags: ms-access

I want to update just one selected column in MS Access 2010. But when I use below update query
MS Access update all `tarih` column values. When I just write the below Select query, it works right. But when I use it in nested update query Update query update all `tarih` column values. What can I do?

```
UPDATE words
SET tarih='12'  
WHERE
  tarih = (SELECT FIRST(tarih)   
           FROM words  
           WHERE tarih='11')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sample query should have the same affect as this one:

```sql
UPDATE words SET tarih='12'
WHERE tarih = '11';
```

In plain English, it will change `tarih` to 12 in all rows where `tarih` is 11.  However, if your `words` table contains multiple rows where `tarih` is 11, and you want `tarah` changed to 12 in only one of those rows, you need a way to tell the database which one of those rows it should update.

For example, if your `words` table includes an autonumber primary key field named `id`, the following query should do what you want.

```sql
UPDATE words SET tarih='12'
WHERE id = DMin("id", "words", "tarih='11'");
```

Try a similar approach adapted to your actual `words` table.  You don't actually need to use an autonumber field.  Another type of primary key field could be used instead.  If your table does not include a primary key consider adding one.  Without a primary key, you could use a combination of fields to uniquely identify which row should be updated.  But if there is no combination of fields which uniquely identifies each row, you won't be able to `UPDATE` only the "first" of several matches.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is a good idea. But DMin doesn't work in MS Access 2010. I use this query UPDATE words SET tarih='12'
WHERE ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM words WHERE tarih='11')